# Error during a sql insertion of a number with scientific notation

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I have a python pandas dataframe and would like to insert it into an oracle database table with cx_Oracle and Sql_alchemy.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',-0.0000000972879685870672402]],columns = ['ID','VALUE'])
dtype = {'ID': VARCHAR(length=50),'VALUE': FLOAT(64)}
df.to_sql('table',con=conn,if_exists  = 'append', index=False,chunksize =100000, dtype = dtype)
```

Unfortunately in the table in Oracle, the value is written as "`-9.728796858706724`", because probably the insert is executed with the value "`-9.728796858706724e-08`" and "`e-08`" is not read.

```
select * from "table";
```

> output:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look right to me, because the literal value appearing in your data frame is not even in scientific notation.

Comment: the insert statement log is:
INSERT INTO table ("ID", "VALUE")
VALUES (:ID, :VALUE)
[parameters: {'ID': 'A','VALUE': -9.72879661276238e-08}];

Comment: How did you determine the value actually contained in the Oracle table?  Can you include the SQL you ran and the exact output?

Comment: I added the output to the question

Comment: Yes I'm sure. You can try to execute the code in your local host and you will get the same result.

Comment: Try using `NUMERIC` not `FLOAT`. See [SQLAlchemy page](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Float) with note.

Comment: Is this [issue](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/300) relevant?

Comment: setting numeric works! thank you!